# how is obtained the observed cell counts in svychisq in R?

Tags: r, survey, chi-squared, contingency

I'm using the function `survey::svychisq()` to test for independence in a two-way contingency table for complex samples.

With `svytable()` I get the observed counts considering the weights defined in `design`, and I would assume that the observed values saved in `svychisq()` objects would be the same, but they are not:

```
svytable(~row.var+col.var, design)
# 330.6634    867.6478    177.1630
# 687.4503    962.5404    228.2926
```

and

```
svychisq(~row.var+col.var, design)$observed
# 404.6712    1061.8411    216.8149
# 841.3126    1177.9722    279.3881
```

provide different results and I couldn't really understand why.

Could someone explain to me how the latter observed values are calculated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$observed` component is a weighted table with weights scaled to sum to the sample size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Given that scaling, it would be correct to interpret the `$stdres` as usual in non-weighted samples (i.e. standardized residuals significant if > 1.96)?

Comment: Yes, roughly. That sort of thing is the point of scaling weights to sum to sample size